# Difference in counts on a Delta Table immediately after write operation

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I've a Databricks job the writes to a certain Delta Table. After the write has been completed, the job is calling another function that reads and calculates some metrics(counts to be specific) on top of the same Delta table.
But the counts/metrics being calculated are less than the actual counts for the the given partition_dates.
Just to verify that the function calculating the metrics is working fine or not, I called the function after the Databricks job got completed and found that the counts were correct in that run.

I feel Delta table is not completely updated by the time I try to read from it, even though the write operation had completed successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what cloud are you using?

Comment: what mode (append, overwrite?) do you use to write to DT and what do you read from it (all or changes only or specific version?)

Comment: @AlexOtt I'm using Azure

Comment: @DariuszKrynicki The writes are either appends or upserts depening on the condition. Once the write is completed, I'm reading directly from the abfs file path(Azure Blob File Storage) of the Delta Table